# VBA Excel Problems and Questions

Tags: vba, excel

New to this forum also new to VBA for Excel. I've took VB before but really long time ago and also I'm not good with coding so I just want to seek for some help here.

```
Sub AFK()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Search As String
    Dim Replacement As String
    Dim Prompt As String
    Dim Title As String
    Dim MatchCase As Boolean

    Prompt = "What is the original value you want to replace?"
    Title = "Search Value Input"
    Search = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

    Prompt = "What is the replacement value?"
    Title = "Search Value Input"
    Replacement = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

       For Each WS In Worksheets
        WS.Columns(1).Find what:=Search, Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        WS.Columns(5).Replace what:=Replacement
    Next

End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is to make the program to look for exactly "5000" or specific values I put and go to another column and change the value in the other column to the inputs that I put. So lets say I want to look for "5000" in column 1 and then after it finds all the "5000" in column 1 it goes to column 5 and replace all the cells that is on the same line as the "5000" with "Nice". I'm not very sure if this explains all but if someone can help or would like to help please comment and ask if the passage is unclear.

Thanks

Comment: you will need to use the range `.Find` method in a loop.  There are some examples on here of doing that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to " look for exactly "5000" " and then you look at xlPart in your code. If you want to match the value exactly you need to use xlWhole. More to your question, store the cell you find into a range variable and then reference off of that to replace.

```
Dim rng As Range
...
Set rng = WS.Columns(1).Find(what:=Search, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
rng.Offset(0, 4).Value = Replacement     ' Offsets 4 columns from found cell and sets value
...
```

If you need to find all instances, you could loop through continually shrinking your search range to one row below last find or just loop over the cells in that column without bothering with any Find functions.

Edit:
I added parentheses around the Find parameters. That should fix your compile error and make the above code work. Fixes it in Excel for me. As far as a loop, the following code steps through all used rows in Excel, checking the first column.

```
Dim i As Integer
...
For i = 1 To WS.UsedRange.Rows.count
    If WS.Cells(i, 1).Value = Search Then
        WS.Cells(i, 5).Value = Replacement
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I used the code that you've gave me and it says a compiling error at  Find. what:=Search, also sorry to ask this but I'm not quite sure how to do a loop

Comment: @Mugen My edits should address both of your comments.